# How can I edit a music playlist?

Tags: music-player, editing

I have a lot of music on my phone and I think I use it rather differently than most people:

- all the music is actually on my phone as mp3s. I do not stream music from anywhere
- my playlists are long - 8 hours, 12 hours, kind of thing
- I generally don't shuffle but want to play them in order, because there's a pattern to the music
- I get new music from time to time and don't just want to stick it on the end

I have tried various things to make playlists but what they all seem to have in common is that "add to playlist" adds it at the end and there's no way to move things around. I understand if you had a 10-song list you could delete 5, add the new thing, then add those 5 back but I'm not doing that with hundreds or thousands of entries.

I don't need to edit the file on my phone -- copying a file out to my PC and editing it with a text editor, then copying it back would be fine for me. After all, I generally add music to the list only when I'm near my PC, where I keep the originals of the music files. I can handle XML, json, or other semi-human-readable formats without complaint.

I'm really not invested in any other features of a music player. I want to bring up the playlist, put my headphones in, hit play, and stop interacting with my phone at that point. I appear to be using "Samsung Music" which came with the phone, but I see I have VLC also installed. I will cheerfully install something different if it gives me the capability to truly edit a playlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLC for Android, as of version 3.5.4, supports reordering media entries in a playlist. To reorder an entry in a playlist:

1. open the playlist;
2. touch and drag the *two horizontal lines* icon (see below image) for a media entry to wherever you want to within the playlist;

   [image: img]